# windows xp start up

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ultimate startup managing application?](https://superuser.com/questions/81671/what-is-the-ultimate-startup-managing-application)

how can i choose less programs than now when windows is starting up?
when i turn on my pc i wait 10 minutes for starting up the windows xp.

Comment: Migrating to superuser in 3...2...1...

Comment: ... 0 ...-1 ...-2 ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility called the System Configuration Utility (msconfig) that you can use. Go to Start -> Run and type in msconfig then hit enter.

There is a startup tab you can use to control which applications fire on startup.

Just a footnote, this may be a better question for [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) is handy for cleaning up your registry, junk files as well as autostart programs.

CCleaner can clean:

> **Internet Explorer**
>   Temporary files, history, cookies, Autocomplete form
>   history, index.dat.
>
> **Firefox**
>    Temporary files, history, cookies, download history, form
>   history.
>
> **Google Chrome**
>   Temporary files, history, cookies, download history,
>   form history.
>
> **Opera**
>    Temporary files, history, cookies. Apple Safari
>
> **Safari**
>    Temporary files, history, cookies, form history. Windows
>
> **Windows**
>    Recycle Bin, Recent Documents, Temporary files and Log files.
>   Registry
>
> **Registry Cleaner**
>    Advanced features to remove unused and old registry
>   entries.

And much more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link on how to use msconfig:
http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/msconfig.htm
and another slightly more detailed: http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/index.html
and a list of essential start up programs for XP: http://www.ehow.com/list_6522557_list-startup-programs-xp-pro.html

Comment: Another utility that is useful is startuprun http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/strun.html - be very careful with MSconfig, It is very easy to mess up your system